# Spring Boot MVC showing 404 Error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ibm.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>course-api-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>course-api-data</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

CourseApiDataApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiDataApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiDataApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

HelloController.java

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String SayHi(){
        System.out.println("Inside Hello Controller");
        return "Hi Arijit";
    }

}
```

Once I am trying to access http://localhost:8080/hello. It is showing 404 error. All the jars are showing in the maven dependencies.

Comment: App-name is missing from the url  isn't it?

Comment: Are you deploying with tomcat embedded?

Comment: try http://localhost:8080/course-api-data/hello

Comment: Are you seeing the message (sysout) in console being printed?

Comment: Your case works with me, when running CourseApiDataApplication as an application from Eclipse, what is log of the console? Do you have another server listening to port 8080?

Comment: perhaps you miss `@ResponseBody` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe Not necessary, as the controller is `@RestController`.

Comment: @NiVeR my bad. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Thank You all. It is working. I have re-created the workspace. I feel it was Jar issue and also version control